# Task does not capture keystrokes

Tags: c#, keyboard, task

This is partly a keystroke/focus question and Task/Sleep question I put some sample code to show what I do. The exact computing is slightly different and needs more resource. This code doesn't work because  no key is catched while in the loop. The only way I can get it to work is to put a MessageBox in the loop. How can I make this work? I was thinking about a sleep or a doevents but I couldn't get it to work.

```
    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public async Task<bool> Execute()
    {
        globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Escape);
        gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);

        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            bool reponses = await DoLongLoopingTask(someData,cts.Token);
            return true;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Stop By User");            }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Internal Error");
        }

        cts=null;


        return true;
    }

    void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Escape Pressed");
        if (cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
    }

    async Task<bool> DoLongLoopingTask(List<Object> someData, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        int resultCuml=0;
        foreach (Object data in someData)
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            resultCuml+=data*11; 
        }
        return resultCuml>1012824;
    }
```

What I really want is a Some part of code that can be interrupted while running in background. Task may or may not be the good solution if something else is better I am open to change it.

Comment: You will have to stop using a Task, that cannot go anywhere.  Mouse and keyboard hooks can only work when your program has a dispatcher loop, Application.Run().  When the user manipulates the mouse or keyboard, he expects something *visible* to happen.  Do not skip the visible part, use the Windows Forms or WPF project template.

Comment: @HansPassant The loops actually does a com object call to show some information in the console of an other application. So the users is just thinking when he press escape the process will stop. Do you think I should not use task and only put evrything at the same place and have a global variable verification?